# how to give the edit url and delete url in jqgrid and it maps to django urls.py

Tags: jquery, django, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid to show all records which are related to my table userprofile and 
personalinfo model .

i wanted to map the each record in a jqgrid should be editable with my django

urls.py this file contained the urls like below

url(editrecord/id, view.edit_myrecord),
url(deleterecord/id, view.delete_myrecord).

edit url recirected to django template and would be editable from the template and
delete record url should delete on gird only. 
how do i give the url map on jqgrid?